# Haskell function iter result

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell and I am working on a problem for this function:

```
iter :: (t -> t) -> t -> [t]
iter f a = a : iter f (f a)
myList = iter (\x -> x + 2) 1
```

My understanding of this is that:

iter takes two arguments (t->t) and t and returns a list of [t].

I am confused on the next part:

```
iter f a = a : iter f (f a)
```

is myList [1,3] or am I thinking about it in the wrong way?

Or would it be [1,3,5,7..]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myList` does, indeed, represent the infinite list `[1,3,..]`. However, the list is generated lazily; the recursive call to `iter` is only made when required. Consider taking the head of `myList`:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x

head myList == head (iter (\x -> x + 2) 1)  -- definition of myList
            == head (1 : iter (\x -> x + 2) ((\x -> x + 2) 1)) -- definition of iter
            == 1 -- definition of head
```

The recursive call to `iter` specified by the definition of `iter` is never made, because `head` never tries to consume the tail of `myList`.

---

I'll note here that `iter` is really an example of a *corecursive* function, not a recursive function. Haskell's non-strict evaluation blurs the distinction between the two. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/144274/206609.